# Detecting if response is a BLOB in Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, appcelerator

I'm trying to detect whether a user has a photo assigned to their account via an API call to a web service.

If there is I can read it using:

```
this.responseData
```

If the user doesn't have an image, instead of [object TiBlob] being output from responseData I get an error string back.

here is a sample of that:

```
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>CA46C2292C8551EC</RequestId>.....
```

I'd like to be able to detect it so I can prevent an image cache taking place.

I've tried all sorts of combos, searching through strings etc. This is where I got to, but it just throws an undefined error.

```
var responseString = this.responseData;    
if (responseString.includes('Error') == true) {
                            // don't request the cover builder
                        } else {

                        // handle the response
    }
```

Any ideas how I can achieve it?

Simon

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by using onerror and therefore there was no need to check for a BLOB